# Split/Tokenize/Split string over set of strings returned from ArrayList

Tags: java, string, arraylist, split, tokenize

I am getting set of strings returning from ArrayList.

This is how I got string while iterating through ArrayList.

```
Welcome|
To|
Stackoverflow|
;
Welcome|
To|
Zootopia|
;
This|
is|
last - String|
;
```

I'd like to tokenize the string based on ';' like this,

This is what I've done:

```
for(String str: arrayList) {
    //System.out.println(str);
    if(str.contains(";")) {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str,";");
        while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            System.out.println(st.nextToken());
        }
    }
}
```

That's what I'm expecting to be:

```
Welcome|To|Stackoverflow- one token
Welcome|To|Zootopia - one token
This|is|last-String|- one token
```

(Because Lets take this first String: `Welcome|To|Stackoverflow` - then further I want to split it on '|' - so I can get separate tokens)

After that I'd want to parse through this '|' character. Is there any better approach for doing this?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: What do you expect your final output to be?

Comment: By wanting *"to tokenize"*, so you mean you want to *concatenate* the strings? --- If the strings are already separated, why concatenate them just to split them again? Or does *"parse through this '|'"* mean something else?

Comment: @Daniel, I've updated my question based on your comment

Comment: @Andreas, thanks for taking it to my attention. Although, how would you propose the idea for doing that way? - Just split from ; and then split from |, without concatenating them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead.

```
class Tokenizer {
    //for Java older than 8
    public static String joinString(Iterable<String> strings, String separator) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String sep = "";
        for(String s: strings) {
            sb.append(sep).append(s);
            sep = separator;
        }
        return sb.toString();                           
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>() {{
            add("Welcome|");
            add("To|");
            add("Stackoverflow|");
            add(";");
            add("Welcome|");
            add("To|");
            add("Zootopia|");
            add(";");
            add("This|");
            add("is|");
            add("last - String|");
            add(";");
        }};

        //String in = String.join("", strings);
        String in = joinString(strings, "");

        for(String outerToken : in.split(";")) {
            System.out.println(outerToken);
            for(String innerToken : outerToken.split("\\|")) {
                System.out.println("\t" + innerToken);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for StringTokenizer Info and your code works fine too- but I'm wondering how am I supposed to break from ';'- when my String is what I've added to the top of my question. Any ideas?

Comment: join method is undefined for Type String

Comment: Are you use java older than 8?

Comment: Yes, I'm Using Java 1.6, This seems to be introduced in Java 8. Well great to learn that :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111521/discussion-between-inityk-and-sergey-gornostaev).